# How to convert postgresql dump after Powershell encoding?

Tags: postgresql, powershell, character-encoding

I use on Windows Server 2019 scheduled job as

```
powershell & 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12.3-7.1C\bin\pg_dump.exe' basename > bn.bak
```

And after that I tried to import bn.bak on other base, but Postgre said me that

> "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff"

File Util gave

> Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators

So, I understand that Powershell 5.1 use ">" as Out-File and use default Encoding UTF-16LE.
But how can I import that file on my base? I tried this ways:

1. iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 bn.bak -o conv1.bak
2. get Powershell 7.0 and use "Get-Content .\bn.bak -Encoding utf8NoBom"

[image]

But all this ways gave me same thing - all latin symbols and numbers shows normal, all Cyrillic symbols shows cracked.

Can this dump still be saved? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can control how the dump file is created you can use the `-f` argument of `pgdump` to write to a file instead of using `>`. And control the encoding with the `-E` option.

Solution found here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281119/postgresql-pg-dump-e-encoding-option-not-working

Postgres manual pgdump
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

EDIT: added some extra links/info on pg_dump

Answer (score 0):

Faced this same problem all day; there's a simple trick.

Open the file in notepad++ go to encoding and change it to UTF8 and save. Filesize should be halved now. This worked for me.

I tried to make an UTF8 export, with this command:

```
.\pg_dump.exe -U postgres -h remotehost -d dbName --encoding utf8 > "C:\Users\me\Documents\project\Migration\backup.sql"
```

but that didn't work as intended for me.